# is there any method to find out if filter is applied on any chart in dashboard?

Tags: dc.js

`_chart.hasFilter()` method returns true if the filter is applied on particular chart or false otherwise.

But I have multiple charts on the dashboard. I want a method or property which can tell if a filter is applied on any chart in the dashboard?

Comment: I didn't see the question here because the tag was wrong. Please use the `dc.js` tag for the charting library; `dc` is a classic unix "desktop calculator" command.

Comment: Answered here: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1305